# post value's text field OrderForm

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have multiple books that people can order. All those books are stored in a MySQL database.
People can enter value's (INT) into a textfield. Example: Book One value = [5].
But when I enter submit it will only show the last entered value of that textfield.

How can I arrange, that if people only enter value's in some textfields and then hit submit they see what product they ordered and the value with it. Thanks :)

My code

```
            <table width="990">
        <form name="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td width="93" class="main">Bestelnummer</td>
            <td width="550" class="main">Titel</td>
            <td width="100" class="main">Categorie</td>
            <td width="150" class="main">Type Onderwijs</td>
            <td width="80" class="main">Groep</td>
            <td width="50" class="main">Prijs</td>
            <td width="40" class="main">Aantal</td>
        </tr>
<?php
    // Laat Resultaten zien
    $s = "SELECT * FROM producten ORDER BY id ASC";
    $sql = (mysql_query($s))or die ("FOUT: " . mysql_error());   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    { 
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='93'>" .$row['bestelnummer']. "</td>"; 
        echo "<td width='550'><a href='".$row['link']."' target='_blank' title='".$row['titel']."' >" .$row['titel']. "</a></td>"; 
        echo "<td width='100'>" .$row['categorie']. "</td>";
        if ($row['onderwijs'] == "BO") { echo "<td width='150'>Basis Onderwijs</td>"; } elseif ($row['onderwijs'] == "VO") { echo "<td width='150'>Voortgezet Onderwijs</td>"; } else { }
        echo "<td width='80'>" . $row['groep'] . "</td>"; 
        if ($row['prijs'] == 0) { echo "<td width='50'><i>gratis</i></td>"; } else { echo "<td width='50'>&euro; " .$row['prijs']. "</td>"; }
        echo "<td width='40'><input type='text' name='nummer".$id."' title='nummer".$id."' class='aantal' maxlength='4' /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Plaats bestelling" class="verzend"/></td>
        </tr>
        </form> 
        </table>
        <?php if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if (empty($_POST['aantal']))
            {
                echo "L33g";    
            }
            else
            {
                $_POST['nummer".$id."'];
            }
        }?>
```

Comment: Well for a start, your `SELECT` statement needs a `WHERE` statement. As in `SELECT * FROM producten WHERE bestelnummer="5" ORDER BY id ASC`

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using an array so use

```
<input type='text' name='nummer[".$id."]' title='nummer".$id."' class='aantal' maxlength='4' />
```

Then replace

```
$_POST['nummer".$id."'];
```

with

```
foreach($_POST['nummer'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```